# p:effect doesn't work with h:outputLink

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i have a **p:effect** inside **h:outputLink** as follows:

```
    <h:panelGrid id="closed_notebook" styleClass="book_wrapper"
    style="width:455px;margin-left: 400px;" columns="2"
    columnClasses="middle,cover">


    <h:panelGroup id="middle_closed" layout="block">

    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup id="left_closed" layout="block">


        <h:outputLink value="javascript:void(0)">   
           <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/book.png" />
           <p:effect for="closed_notebook"  type="clip" event="click" />                           
        </h:outputLink>




    </h:panelGroup>


</h:panelGrid>
```

i want when clicking on the link that contains the image, all the panelGrid disappears, but it doesn't work, i get no action.

also, i want after the panelGrid disappears to show another hidden panelGrid with animation, how to do that ?

please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `<f:param name="mode" value="'hide'" />`

Another important thing might be to add and `id` attribute to `<h:outputLink`

> Note: It’s important for components that have the effect component as a child to have an
>   assigned id because some components do not render their clientId’s if you don’t give them an id
>   explicitly.(Primefaces Manual)

Like this:

```
<h:outputLink id="someUniqeIdMightBeAMust" value="javascript:void(0)">  
    <p:effect for="closed_notebook"  type="clip" event="click">    
        <f:param name="mode" value="'hide'" />  
    </p:effect>
</h:outputLink>
```

As to the other part of showing another hidden panelGrid ,

You can try playing with `speed` and `delay` attributes , limit the first animation to 1000 and begin with the second animation after 1001 milliseconds...

```
<h:outputLink id="someUniqeIdMightBeAMust" value="javascript:void(0)">  
    <p:effect for="closed_notebook"  type="clip" event="click" speed="1000">    
        <f:param name="mode" value="'hide'" />  
    </p:effect>
    <p:effect for="middle_closed" type="clip" event="click" delay="1001">    
        <f:param name="mode" value="'show'" />  
    </p:effect>
</h:outputLink>
```

Comment: the issue was that i was not setting an id for the outputlink, thanks man.